# C Strings, Pointers, Puts

Tags: c, string, printf, getchar, puts

I have been studying a code on Programming in C lately. I got stuck here while dealing with two dimensional strings and pointers. Also the functions printf(), putchar(), and puts() are confusing! Please help me out with the following snippet:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char wer[3][4]= {"bag", "let", "bud"};
    char (*ptr)[4]=wer;
    printf("%d   %d   %d\n",ptr, ptr+1, ptr+1); // points to bag, let and bud respectively 
    printf("%d   %d   %d\n",wer, wer+1, wer+1); // points to bag, let and bud respectively

    printf("%d   %d   %d\n", (*ptr), (*ptr+1), (*ptr +2)); // points to b,a,g respectively

    printf("%s\n",*(ptr+1)); //prints let
    printf("%s\n", (ptr+1)); //prints let
    printf("%s\n", (*ptr +1)); //prints ag


    puts(*(ptr+1)); //prints let
    //puts((ptr+1)); //gives error
    puts((*ptr+1)); //prints ag


    putchar(**(ptr+1));//prints l
    putchar(*(*ptr +1));//prints a

    return 0;
}
```

I want to know why do  `*(ptr+1)` and `(ptr+1)` both work for `printf` while  `(ptr+1)` gives an error for `puts`. Also I know that `putchar` takes an integer argument. Why do we use double pointer here?

Comment: print the pointers using `%p`

Comment: Also, I request you to re-read the man pages and double-check the supplied data types. :)

Comment: "gives an error" : which error ?

Comment: I have tried as you mention code snippet in gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)  and I didn't see any error during compilation time or runtime.

Comment: [Error] cannot convert 'char (*)[4]' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int puts(const char*)'

Answer (score 1):

Your `ptr` variable is of type `char (*)[4]` (a pointer to `char` array). The prototype of `puts` is:

```
int puts(const char *s);
```

So, as your compiler probably says, `puts` expects a pointer on `char` but you give an argument of type `char (*)[4]`.

> I want to know why do *(ptr+1) and (ptr+1) both work for printf while (ptr+1) gives an error for puts.

The argument types are not checked on the call to `printf` (probably because `printf` takes variadic arguments). Add `-Wall` in your `CFLAGS` to add more warnings and your compiler should emit a warning about this.

> Also I know that putchar takes an integer argument. Why do we use double pointer here?

You dereference `ptr` twice to get a `char` (you can also do `(*ptr)[1]`). This `char` is implicitly cast into `int` when you call putchar.

Comment: `char * [4]` is an array of 4 char pointers, `char (*) [4]` is a pointer to array of 4 chars.

Comment: That helped and brought some clarity. Thanks.

Comment: If the arguments are not checked on the call to printf, then how (when) is the output decided? Also how is it possible to accept arguments of type const * char and char, both?

Comment: Arguments are not checked by the compiler. The output is decided at run time, the format string is parsed by the `printf` function.